# How to hide a iframe upon clicking on it with Jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, hide

How to hide a iframe with jquery. When user click on iframe (example iframe containing a google ADD ) it should hide without disturbing the iframe code. How can i achieve this with Jquery.

Thank You

Comment: just pay to get ride of the google ad

Comment: @Mauricio  LOL Right .. @KillerFish Dude dont try with google .. if you planing to .

Comment: Forget about google add . atleast can u people hide the iframe with jquery on click. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would have a link with id "toggle" right outside the iframe (on your page):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle">-<span style="display:none">+</span></a>
```

Here's how you would link that up to hide the ad using jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     var toggler=$("#toggle");
     toggler.click(function(){
      $("iframe").slideToggle('slow', function(){
         // or specify a specific iframe using $("#iframe_id")
        $("#toggle span").toggle();
      });
     });
    }); 
</script>
```