# how to open a link in iFrame

Tags: iframe, lightbox, area

This is my code:

```
<area shape="design-principles" coords="598,385,695,455" rel="lightbox" href="http://www.google.com" target="frame1"/>
<iframe name="frame1" Width="500px" Height="100px" style="overflow:hidden;">
 <p> Browser does not support iframes </p>
</iframe>
```

I have an image, I'm targeting `onClick` of a specific location of the image(hence used the `<area>` tag).

The problem is, http://www.google.com is not opening in the `iframe`.

Also, I want the `iframe` to "go away" `onMouseOut`

Answer (score 0):

The below loads google or yahoo in the iframe.

```
<img src ="http://www.noahsanimalfigurines.com/catalog/images/cf/oce133.jpg" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap ="#planetmap" />
<map name="planetmap">
 <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com', 'frame1')"  alt="Sun" />
 <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,150,150" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', 'frame1')"  alt="Moon" />  
</map>

<iframe name="frame1" Width="500px" Height="100px" style="overflow:hidden;">
  <p> Browswer does not support iframes </p>
</iframe>
```

You can show/hide the iframe using jquery:
     [How to hide a iframe upon clicking on it with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835904/how-to-hide-a-iframe-upon-clicking-on-it-with-jquery)

Comment: Any reason you didn't use plain html and the target attribute instead?

Comment: @jordan No. This works too:

      <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="http://www.google.com" target="frame1" alt="Sun" />
      <area shape="rect" coords="100,100,150,150" href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="frame1"  alt="Moon" />

But I thought it was a nice way to introduce jquery/javascript for the onMouseOut.